# WPF page resize

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, resize

I am developing an application in Visual Studio using C# and WPF. I have made a basic structure of WPF Pages with navigation conntrols to move from one page to another. I can not make the Pages maximize on startup. I want to imitate this window behaviour 
 - WindowStyle = "None" - make window borderless
 - WindowState = "Maximized" - make window fullscreen
Basicaly I want my Pages to go full screen without borders. I'm not able to resize them. I use Pages instead of windows because I am making a weblike offline desktop app and have a lot of different screens that go from one to another and I want them to be displayed in one "window" and not have the user open and close windows to pass from one screen to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a full screen window that contains a [Frame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame.aspx) for page navigation.

```
<Window x:Class="Pages.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        WindowStyle="None" WindowState="Maximized">
    <Frame Source="Page1.xaml">
    </Frame>
</Window>
```

Get more info in [Navigation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx).

Comment: But I have many pages not just one. My Login is a Page, Main Menu is another page and I have 2 Groups of pages for different screens. How is that going to make tham all full screen and borderless. I can't wrap my head around this piece of code that defines tha Page With and Border,no matter what I enter it starts up with a auto default size that I can not resize! All examples on the internet are with forms or windows and I need pages because I am making a sort of Diary like app and need different screens. 
 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="1366"

Comment: Frame supports navigation. That's why i posted the link to the Navigation Overview article in MSDN.

Comment: Maybe I'm not very clear. I have a multy screen app and use WPF Pages
I want to be able to resize the Page. My structure is not based on Windows or Forms, it is based on Pages. Maybe my aproach to the application is not correct and need to use UserControls, I have no idea. But there has to be a way to manipulate Page size and layout.